# C#: Set time to start week

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar

I need to find week number of year, and a new week start at Friday 10:00 AM.
It's seem to be easy if I only set the day to start is Friday, that's mean 0:00 AM Friday
, but..how can i set it's 10:00 AM Friday?
Currently, I used this code the calculate week number

```
  private int GetWeek(DateTime date)
  {
            DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
            Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;

            return cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, DayOfWeek.Friday);
  }
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the time to determine what what week you are in:

```
private int GetWeek(DateTime date)
{
    DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;

    var weeknum= cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, DayOfWeek.Friday);
    if (date.TimeOfDay.Hours<10)
    {
        weeknum -= 1;
    }

    return weeknum;
}
```

However, before you just use this solution, you should think about some of your cases that can come up based on when a Friday falls.  For example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetWeekHelper(DateTime.Parse("2014-01-03 11:00:00"));  //2
    GetWeekHelper(DateTime.Parse("2015-01-02 11:00:00"));  //2
    GetWeekHelper(DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 11:00:00"));  //1
    GetWeekHelper(DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 9:00:00"));   //0
}

private void GetWeekHelper(DateTime date)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", date.ToString(), GetWeek(date)));
}
```

Since this is your business logic, you need to determine the correctness of these values.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and your advice ^^!.
I think it'll be correct if you check both date.TimeOfDay.Hours < 10 && date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday. Anyway, you help me to think about the solution :)